# iText PdfWriter doesn't write Arabic properly

Tags: pdf, itext

I tried to write Arabic content to pdf file using PdfWriter(document,FileoutPutStream), but when I opened the pdf file some of lines is over itself so it is unreadable, please is there any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem until I figured out that some fonts just will not display 'foreign' (to them) signs. 
I would suggest you to try using the same font as in a program (probably a notepad or something like that) where the text is displayed properly. It worked perfect for me. 
I opened the file first in notepad and there in Format-> Font... you see the font which was used to open it. Then you will have to find the location of the font, create the font object and give it to e.g. a paragraph before writing it to a document and it will work, at least I hope so. Good luck. :)

Comment: I did like you said but it wrote these characters "???????" instead of Arabic characters

Comment: I do not know what to suggest then... Did you check on iText forum, http://support.itextpdf.com/forum for a similar problem?

Comment: that was a problem but there was another problem , which is I was using MultiColumnText , I changed it to use PdfPTable & PdfPCell and it worked great.